# Select a MultiIndex and a 'normal' column at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Some of my columns are MultiIndex, some are not.
I don't seem to be able to select both of these types at the same time.

For example, I might want the column `['0', 'A']` as well as the column `['2']`.

```
Name    0                       1            2         
Col     A           B                               
0       0.409511    -0.537108   -0.355529    0.212134 
1       -0.332276   -1.087013    0.083684    0.529002 
2       1.138159    -0.327212    0.570834    2.337718
```

`df.loc[:,['0', '2']]` does work to select the three columns. I expect the solution to be something like `df.loc[:,[('0', 'A'), '2']]`, but that doesn't work.

EDIT: the `df.to_dict('tight')` of my actual data:

```
{'index': [('15_22_38', 6, '000156'),
  ('15_22_38', 6, '000157'),
  ('15_22_38', 6, '000158')],
 'columns': [('rotation', 'x'), 'n_frames'],
 'data': [[0.0, 26], [0.0, 26], [0.0, 26]],
 'index_names': ['scene', 'id', 'frame'],
 'column_names': [None]}
```

Comment: Please provide the dataframe constructor when you use multiindex.

Comment: Provide the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as combined Multi and simple Index.

You must have empty strings in your second level (or maybe NaNs?)

```
d = {'index': [0, 1, 2],
 'columns': [(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (1, ''), (2, '')],
 'data': [[0.409511, -0.537108, -0.355529, 0.212134],
  [-0.332276, -1.087013, 0.083684, 0.529002],
  [1.138159, -0.327212, 0.570834, 2.337718]],
 'index_names': [None],
 'column_names': ['Name', 'Col']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='tight')
df
```

You should thus use:

```
df.loc[:, [(0, 'A'), (2, '')]]
```

Output:

```
Name         0         2
Col          A          
0     0.409511  0.212134
1    -0.332276  0.529002
2     1.138159  2.337718
```

Comment: Maybe there shouldn't be such a thing, but the dataframe in front of me does have both kinds of columns. And I don't know what I changed, but the solution I proposed that should be working now actually works

Comment: @qkfsbxjayiedbe it cannot be, please provide the output of `df.to_dict('tight')` as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76066283/edit) to your question.

Comment: Sure. I suppose it wouldn't work if the column index levels were named.